# Usar archivos .js y .css específicos dentro de páginas específicas en una extensión de Chrome

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Esto es un ejemplo, suponiendo que tengo tres archivos css y tres js, pero quiero que cada uno de ellos sea llamado únicamente por su sitio correspondiente (El [.........] es parte del json que omití en el ejemplo):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
[.........................]
  "content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": [
      "https://uno.com/",
      "https://dos.com/",
      "https://tres.com/"
  ],
  "css": ["css/uno.css", "css/dos.css", "css/tres.css"],
  "js": ["js/uno.js", "js/dos.js", "js/tres.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de Google Chrome para [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) se comenta que `content_scripts` es una lista de elementos que contendrá los valores. En tu caso tienes un único elemento y por eso cuando se cumpla alguno de los `matches` se insertarán todos los archivos indicados en la lista de `js` y `css`.

Si lo que quieres que cada uno se cargue con su sitio correspondiente (en `uno.com` se cargará `uno.css` y `uno.js`; en `dos.com` cargará `dos.css` y `dos.js`; etc.) lo que tienes que hacer es crear mútliples elementos dentro de `content_scripts`, uno para cada uno  de los sitios. Algo como esto:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "https://uno.com/" ],
    "css": [ "css/uno.css" ],
    "js": [ "js/uno.js" ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  },
  {
    "matches": [ "https://dos.com/" ],
    "css": [ "css/dos.css" ],
    "js": [ "js/dos.js" ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  },
  {
    "matches": [ "https://tres.com/" ],
    "css": [ "css/tres.css" ],
    "js": [ "js/tres.js" ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
]
```